# How to create multiple timer based on the timestamp of a data in database or delay the popup of the data base on the timestamp or time

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Here I have shopping cart website and when a user check out it will go to the database name checkout. Then the admin will check the details of the user items then click accepted and it will go to db name pending payment. it will then notify the user that 4 hrs from now please pay using any credit card or else it will be deleted. I got a column name timer in my pending payment db which is a timestamp and another column name time which will get the date and time data . Im only doing this type of payment because I still don't know how to create a paypal payment so Im just checking my balance as a way of verification it will be temporary and also to have more choices wether it can be done using timestamp or date in php code like H/h/y/s something like that. Now if a user sends in a data then a timestamp appears in the database or (3/11/2019 5:03pm) for the time . Which will I fetch like this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM pendingpayment;";
$sttmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($sttmt,$sql)){

echo "sql statement failed in displayitems.php line 71";            
}else{
 mysqli_stmt_execute($sttmt);
 $ressult=mysqli_stmt_get_result($sttmt);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($ressult)>0){
 while($rowz=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ressult)){
```

for the timestamp

```
     $rowz=['timestamp'];
```

for the time the user insert a data

```
     $rowz['time'];

     }}}
```

this is the output of the timestamp

```
   2019-03-10 22:41:26
```

and the output of the time is up to you 
now I want to create an alarm in that timestamp or time. that will notify the user 4 hrs from now. For ex. user sends in data at 5pm then admin accepted it at 6 it will notify the user like (4hrs from now please pay or else deleted which has a timer 6-10pm )is it possible using php or js?

or should I delay the popup of the data by 4 hrs from now? like I select * in db then popup only 4 hrs from now based on the timestamp or time

my way of notification is inserting data into the db name notification then I just select * and display it

Comment: This would only work if the user was still hanging around on your site in the first place … I don’t know how you online-shop, but I usually don’t stick around for an hour after check-out.

Comment: so I can't create a timer out of it?or delay the pop up of the data base on the time in db?

Comment: In case I have already left your site an hour ago, who or what do you expect to show me any kind of “popup” now? You could look into browser notifications or something like that - but those are not a trivial thing to implement either.

Comment: and also this is for educational purposes

Comment: sleep function is maybe the solution

Answer (score 0):

the sleep function works in this like

```
 if(isset($_POST['bla'])){
    sleep(10);
 $bla=$_POST['bla'];
  $sql="INSERT INTO checkout(fname) VALUES(?);";
  $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
  echo "error in sql";
  }else{
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$bla);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
}
```

even if the user delete the browser it will still insert the data into the db after 5 seconds